Hive_default_partition error while loading into s3
I was trying to load data into a s3 location as parquet a file in databricks using df.write.mode(“overwrite”).partitionbt(“col”).save(s3path)
Df is created reading from a table using spark sql
But the code fails reading from hive_default_partition folder
I have tried avoiding null values in my sql where key is not null in data frame but still fails with same issue
Is there any way to ignore reading from this default partition or any other solution
explained above I tried avoiding the null values in creating df
